# Kotlin and spring validation without using beans

Tags: spring, validation, kotlin

Anyone knows how if it is possible to use the Spring Validation mechanism in a Rest Controller in Kotlin, while continuing to receive 400 - Bad requests when validation fails?

This works and throws 400 on validation errors:

```
data class Email(@field:Email val email: String)

@PostMapping("/foo")
fun foo(@RequestBody @Valid email: Email): ResponseEntity<Void>
```

But this throw HTTP code 500 instead of 400:

```
@PostMapping("/foo")
fun foo(@RequestBody @Valid @Email email: String): ResponseEntity<Void>
```

I would like to avoid using an intermediate data class or a Controller Advice to do this job.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you see any error message/stack trace in the log?

Comment: nop, all is "normal" : I just got a ConstraintViolationException on method validation in the spring mechanism to call my method [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/7b31a935563b3497f831a9862cdb7dd66c95af7a/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationInterceptor.java#L123)